# Is it possible to expose pipe file from docker container?

Tags: docker, samba, squid, named-pipes

Docker assume one container for one application. I have two apps (samba and squid) what talk to each other with pipe file. Is it possible to expose or share this pipe file between two containers?

Comment: You could break container isolation to do this, but you're really meant to communicate with other containers over the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just mount a common volume where both applications expect to create/see the pipe.